# Making the most of having two group affiliations

Tags: phd, supervision

I am co-supervised by two PIs and I am spending half my time each week in one lab and the other half in the other lab.

My question is, how can I make the most of this situation? What are the pitfalls? How does this differ from being supervised by one person and therefore spending all of one's time in one lab?

I am a PhD student, but I suppose this could also apply to post-docs. If it matters, my field is biology.

Answer (score 1):

When the two PIs are at different universities, you could perform your thesis as a [double degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_degree) (something I did myself), assuming that both universities allow this. One aspect that needs to be taken into account is that if you do so, you need to adhere to the regulations of both institutions, which sometime leads to conflicting requirements. Also you need to align with the bureaucracies of both institutions, which certainly results in some overhead for you.

Anyway, even when the PIs are at the same institution, you can profit from their (hopefully somewhat complementary) expertise. Also you will have a larger network. You will need to balance your time between both research groups, and align their feedback, which is a potential pitfall, but also a learning opportunity.